# Scilab - Finding the average of randomly generated numbers with different indices

Tags: scilab

Say I have a function that generates random integers between say (1,10).

Then, I define a (for loop) which has 5 iterations.

This (for loop) calls the function defined above, and then it checks the value of the integer generated by the function. Depending on the value of the integer, the variable "cost" is decided.

```
function integer = UniformInt(a, b)
    integer =  min( floor( rand()*(b-a) ) + a , b);
endfunction

for i=1:5

    x(i) = UniformInt(1,10);

    if (x(i)<4) then
        cost(i) = 15;

        elseif (4<=x(i) && x(i)<=8) then
        cost(i) = 27;

        else
        cost(i) = 35;

    end

end
```

Now, when I run that and find `x`, say the values generated are:

```
   5.
   9.
   5.
   2.
   2.
```

And so, the different `cost` values will be:

```
   27.
   35.
   27.
   15.
   15.
```

This is all good so far. Now, what I want to do with these results is:

Check how many times each value of `x` appeared. I can do this via Scilab's `tabul` function:

```
9.   1.
5.   2.
2.   2.
```

Now, what I really want to code is:

`x=9` only showed up once, so, the average of `cost` is `35/1 = 35`.

`x=5` showed up twice, so, the average of `cost` is `(27+27)/2 = 27`.

`x=2` showed up twice, so, the average of `cost` is `(15+15)/2 = 15`.

How would I do that?

For posterity, a code in which the answer provided by user @Stéphane Mottelet would be useful (because my code above is trivial) is as follows:

```
function integer = UniformInt(a, b)
    integer =  min( floor( rand()*(b-a) ) + a , b);
endfunction

for i=1:5

    x(i) = UniformInt(1,10);

    if (x(i)<4) then
        cost(i) = 15*rand();

        elseif (4<=x(i) && x(i)<=8) then
        cost(i) = 27*rand();

        else
        cost(i) = 35*rand();

    end

end
```

Now the cost values are multiplied by a random number, and so,
if the value of say `x=10` showed up 2 times, the average cost when `x=10` will not simply be `(35+35)/2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do like this, but the answer is quite trivial since for now the value of cost is the same for a given x value (I suppose your real application draws random values of cost)

```
t = tabul(x);
for k = 1:size(t,1)
  avg(k) = mean(cost(x == t(k)));
end
```

Comment: That's correct, the cost values are multiplied by another random number, so in that case the answer will not be trivial.

This is an ingenious and elegant way of doing it! I would have never thought of that 
myself! Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, that's the way it has to be done in Scilab (or Matlab). I have removed the `find` as it is useless since Scilab allows boolean indexing.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realized that. That's a really helpful feature.